# How to make changes in jsp effected

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, hotdeploy

I am using Tomcat 5.0.30, JDK 1.5.0_17 and Eclipse as IDE.  Now the issue is when I made changes to any JSP pages I have to build (ant build) the project and have to deploy the war file to the Tomcat Manager to view the change. Is there any method which help to view the change without deploying the war file to the Tomcat Manager. Please give a solution. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a exploded one for development.

I usually link my Tomcat to my dev directory, so it can pick the changes as soon as it is done.

Comment: can you please tell how to do that. I am new to Tomcat and Eclipse

Comment: Add a Context entry for your app and point it to your dev directory http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [Eclipse Tomcat Plugin](http://www.eclipsetotale.com/tomcatPlugin.html), it will handle all that for you.

Comment: hi plz can you tell me how to link Tomcat to dev directory?

Answer (score 0):

Extract your .war file into the $TOMCAT/webapps folder

Eg: extract yourapp.war to $TOMCAT/webapps/yourapp (Your WEB-INF directory should be at $TOMCAT/webapps/yourapp/WEB-INF)

Changes made to jsps under this folder will be visible immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of doing that is without much knowledge of how it works,

in my environment,

using eclipse 3.5 with j2ee support, then default settings are auto publish and auto build. So as long as you don't change .java files, you can keep working without re-deploy.

Comment: i am using eclipse 3.3,but dont know the default sttings. where I can view this

Comment: if you are using j2ee version of it, then i guess probably it has those settings also. if you dont use, just switch, btw why dont u use 3.5 eclipse?